# C libpq: get float value from numeric

Tags: c, postgresql, floating-point, decimal, libpq

I have a table with float value represented using numeric type. How can I get float value from this field using libpq lib?

There is a specialized format for float type in postgres, but I have to work with existing database with numeric fields. I haven't found information about it in the Postgres documentation so every info is appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? How did (or didn't) that work? What problems have you encountered?

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg Added additional info

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/datatype-numeric.html which type is it?

Comment: @stark NUMERIC(18, 15)

Comment: [`PQgetvalue`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/libpq-exec.html#LIBPQ-PQGETVALUE) might work? Shouldn't be to hard to convert the string to a floating point value.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thanks! My question may seem rather obvious - I'm simply new to postgres.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly you *can't* get an accurate float representation of a `numeric`. Not for any arbitrary `numeric` anyway.

`numeric` is arbitrary-precision decimal floating point represented internally as binary-coded decimal strings. It's usually sent to and from the client as a text string of decimal digits.

float/double are *fixed-precision* *binary* floating point. They [cannot represent all decimal numbers without rounding errors](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/101163/56391), and they can't represent unlimited precision numbers because they have fixed precision.

Your `numeric`s are `numeric(18,15)`, i.e. precision 18, scale 15. `double precision` has 15-17 significant digits, depending on the exact value. So you may lose data due to rounding.

If you don't mind that, you can use the usual methods for parsing a floating point value from text, like `sscanf`, on the textual output of `PQgetvalue`.

If you need to retain accurate decimal floating point: avoid rounding losses and preserve exact values across round trips, you're going to need to use a decimal floating point library. For any `numeric` you'd need arbitrary-precision decimal support. For `numeric(18,15)` you can *almost* fit it in a IEEE-754:2008 64-bit decimal, but you really need 128-bit decimal to be safe.

Libraries include:

- [Intel's Decimal Floating Point library](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-decimal-floating-point-math-library)
- IBM's decimal floating point library
- [GNU MFPR](http://www.mpfr.org/) - arbitrary precision
- [decNumber](http://speleotrove.com/decimal/decnumber.html)
- [libmpdec](http://www.bytereef.org/mpdecimal/index.html) - arbitrary precision

Newer gcc includes support for IEEE-754:2008 floating point too.

Python has arbitrary-precision decimal with the `decimal.Decimal` type (`import decimal`). `psycopg2` should be able to use this. So you might consider this as an alternative.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation!

Comment: assume I have char pointer from PQgetvalue. How can I understand for which postgres type I can cast this pointer to analog type in C and for which I have to use additional functions (like atof)? For example, postgres integer versus postgres numeric.

Comment: @Sas This is really a separate topic. Please post a new question if you aren't able to answer it yourself with a quick search.